# Функция таймера

Tags: javascript

Скажите пожалуйста, у меня есть метод 
    `setTimeOut()` каторый выполняет заданую функцию один раз через определенный отрывок времени, а мне нужно что бы задання функция выполнялась каждый раз через определёный интервал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval('функция', время в миллисекундах);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval("functionName()",1000);
// где functionName - имя вызываемой функции
// а 1000 - промежуток времени соответственно
```

Немного дополню - чтобы убрать интервал необходимо вызвать `clearInterval`, например:

```
var someInterval = setInterval("functionName()",1000);  // устанавливаем
clearInterval(someInterval);     // убираем
```

Comment: @AlexWindHope исправь свою ошибку.

Comment: Аааа, значит, функцию надо в скобках писать... а я писал без скобок, как мне порекомендовал друг и ничего не работало... спасибо большое.